# How to hide/show on div click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that I'm trying to show and hide on a click of another div

The code I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".logoo").click(function(){
        $("ul.secondone").show(1000);
    });

});
```

How do I add the hide function as well? I tried changing the .show to .hide but it didn't work.

Comment: Part of Stack Overflow is you have to do research and try to solve the problem before asking here.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Open up your console of your browser. And first try to hide/show the element with $(el).hide()/show(). If that doesnt work. Something is wrong with your selector. If it works something is wrong with your click handler

Comment: With about 5 seconds of work - you can find many many many answers to this. I just googled 'how to toggle hide show jquery stack overflow'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Okay sorry for asking this question in a hurry I have figured the code out.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.logoo').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('ul.secondone').toggle('show');
    });
})
```